# How to disable RX led on Arduino Micro

Tags: spi, arduino-micro

I am using the RX LED pin as CS for my SPI connection and experiencing problems while debugging and communicating via SPI. Is it possible somehow to disable the RX blinking while using the serial monitor?

Comment: If there isn't an easier way, you could probably neuter the TXLED and RXLED macros in pins_arduino.h. you could make a new board type called "micro-no-led" to have both options available.

Comment: When you say `neuter` do you mean remove them by clearing the defines? I assume removing them completely will cause compilation errors in USBCore.cpp

Comment: Sorry; By neuter I mean replacing them with a statement that compiles, but has no effect.